# Display content with display.php and display.tpl in PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop

I read http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Displaying+content+on+the+front+office and I try to create a display.php file and a display.tpl file.

But I don't realize for sure where they must be put. 
Because it says a place for display.php 
("Let's create the display.php file that it targets, with a minimal content, and put it in the module's root folder") 
and after that it says another place for the same file 
("Let's explore display.php, our first PrestaShop front-end controller, stored in the /controllers/front folder of the module's main folder:").

I really also don't understand next sentence:
("That display.php file will be rewritten into a front-end controller [..]").

And when it is about display.tpl I don't actually get where I must put it. I wonder that the best place is /controllers/front.

Can you tell me where will I be wrong? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Have a look at some examples of PS modules in the `/modules` folder. In short: the FrontController goes into `<module>/controllers/front`, and the views (`.tpl` files) into the `<module>/views/templates/front` folder.

Comment: Do you mean do I must create in my module /controllers/front and /views/template/front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put **the controller** in controllers/front

The views all in:

views/templates/(front|admin|hook)

if is frontController, just do `$this->setTemplate('mytpl.tpl');` on init() function